# Dependency injection with parameters to object

Tags: php, laravel

I got the follow code:

```
public function after(Validator $validator)
{
    $tokenFile=TokenArchivo::findOrFail($this->input('id'));
    $start_date = new Carbon($tokenFile->expiration);
    $now = Carbon::now();
```

But i want to use Dependency injection for Carbon. But if i do that:

```
public function after(Validator $validator, Carbon $carbon)
```

I cant do:

```
$carbon($tokenFile->expiration)
```

How i can do dependency injection in my case?

Comment: What would you expect `$carbon` to be if you injected it? If you did inject, why would you need to call `$carbon($token->expiration)`? I'm a little confused at what you're trying to do.

Comment: @TimLewis if i inject Carbon, i need to create a new object of carbon passing a parameter $token->expiration. How i do that?

Comment: The way you have now actually. If you inject `Carbon $carbon`, then `$carbon` would be an instance of `Carbon`, which is a date. `$carbon` would be something like `2019-11-26 14:32:00`, and not usable as `$carbon($variable)`

Comment: @TimLewis the it's impossible to use dependency injection in this case?

Comment: Well no, it's not impossible, but it wouldn't do what you're thinking it does. Unless you're directly injecting the result of `$tokenFile->expiration` (which I'm not sure how you'd do here, not sure what is calling `after()`), then there is no need to do injection.

Comment: @TimLewis Why you wouldn't do that? it's a bad practice?

Comment: Do you need this injected to meet some testing requirements?  You ... could ... (not should) Inject Carbon into the constructor for the object/class containing after().  Then you could pass expires into a function that sets up $this->carbonation.  I guess.

Comment: It is normal to create new versions of Carbon objects? it seems weird to do it like so.